# LINQ to SQL associations?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a Posts class and that post can have one file and that file can have many tags

I want to iterate through the files in a post and show all the files tags

```
foreach(File f in Post.Files)
{
    f.Tags
}
```

What do I need in this foreach to get the top tag? there will only ever be one.

i tried

```
f.Tags.Select(n => n)
```

with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, You can always omit .Select(n => n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first tag for a file, use this:

```
f.Tags.First()
```

If you have one file per post and multiple tags per file though, something like this might be more appropriate:

```
foreach( Tag t in Post.Files.First().Tags ) {
    // Do something with t
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posts.SelectMany(pPost => pPost.Files.SelectMany(pFile => pFile.Tags.Select(pTag => pTag)))